# Can you program windows 95 code on windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there any difference in the windows 7 api vs windows 95 say for creating windows, dialogue boxes and buttons?

Comment: Not sure, so I post this as a comment and not as an answer, but I believe your IDE should have flags that let you define the target version of Windows, so that should be OK. These flags define some macros that enable some APIs and disable others.

Comment: Windows 95... ROFL... Tempted to VTC this as "Too Localized". :P

Comment: Yes, Windows95 includes the full set of `FsckIt`, `ItsFscked` and `GetFscked` API calls where Windows 7 has hidden them away.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no -- most code for Windows 95 should compile and run on Windows 7, but Windows 7 also adds quite a bit of new "stuff" that simply wasn't present in Windows 95.

Comment: And deprecates (or sometimes even removes) stuff that was present in Windows 95.

Comment: @chris ...like Windows95 ;)

Comment: @chris: Yes, some stuff is removed (thus the "*most* code"), but the vast majority remains.

Comment: The more recent versions of Visual Studio introduced a new dependency in the C runtime libraries that prevents you from targeting Windows 2000 (and maybe also XP RTM) without some trickery.  This might be possible, but probably not with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamentals haven't changed that much, and because Windows has been good about backwards compatibility you'll find that things like dialog boxes and buttons are almost identical.

Since Windows 95 hasn't been supported for many years now, you may need to find an older compiler and other bits of the toolset to build a proper executable.

Answer (score 2):

For creating Windows, no, if you program with the SDK. But the look and feel of elements created by the OS will follow the OS style ( Windows in Windows 95 ans 7 are different).